# match values in dataframes with values in a column

Tags: r

I have two data.frames that looks like these ones:

```
>df1
 V1
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e

>df2
 V1     V2
  1  a,k,l
  2  c,m,n
  3  z,b,s
  4  l,m,e
  5  t,r,d
```

I would like to match the values in `df1$V1` with those from `df2$V2`and add a new column to `df1` that corresponds to the matching and to the value of `df2$V1`, the desire output would be:

```
>df1
 V1  V2
  a   1
  b   3
  c   2
  d   5
  e   4
```

I've tried this approach but only works if `df2$V2` contains just one element:

```
match(as.character(df1[,1]), strsplit(as.character(df2[,2], ",")) -> idx
df1$V2 <- df2[idx,1]
```

Many thanks

Comment: What if, for example, "a" appeared more than once in `df2$V2`? What should the result be?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AnandaMahto, the values in `df1$V1` only shoud appear once in `df2$V2`, but if there are any repetition then the two values separated by a colon "," would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `grep`, which will return the position of the string found:

```
sapply(df1$V1, grep, x = df2$V2)
# a b c d e 
# 1 3 2 5 4
```

If you expect repeats, you can use `paste`.

Let's modify your data so that there is a repeat:

```
df2$V2[3] <- "z,b,s,a"
```

And modify the solution accordingly:

```
sapply(df1$V1, function(z) paste(grep(z, x = df2$V2), collapse = ";"))
#     a     b     c     d     e 
# "1;3"   "3"   "2"   "5"   "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach:

```
library(qdap)
key <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(df2$V2), ","), df2$V1)
df1$V2 <- as.numeric(df1$V1 %l% key)

df1

##   V1 V2
## 1  a  1
## 2  b  3
## 3  c  2
## 4  d  5
## 5  e  4
```

First we used `strsplit` to create a named list.  Then we used qdap's `lookup` operator `%l%` to match values and create a new column (I converted to numeric though this may not be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tyler's answer, but in base using `stack`:

```
df.stack <- stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df2$V2), ","), df2$V1))
transform(df1, V2=df.stack$ind[match(V1, df.stack$values)])
```

produces:

```
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b  3
3  c  2
4  d  5
5  e  4
```

One advantage of splitting over grep is that with grep you run the risk of searching for `a` and matching things like `alabama`, etc. (though you can be careful with the patterns to mitigate this (i.e. include word boundaries, etc.).

Note this will only find the first matching value.